# Plotting in matlab in axis off mode

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have put a little part of my code

`figure,
plot(Clip_M_EF(New_M_index(:,1),1),'xg'),
axis off,
hold on,
plot(New_M_EF_MS,'*r'),
hold on,
plot(Clip_M_EF_GS(New_M_index(:,1),1),'+b')`

You see, because I have set axis mode into "off" the following plots cannot be plotted into any axis. But my teacher wants me to be able to plot them in the axis despite having them the axis in off mode. He says, "Please modify your code in a way that axes, titles, are displayed irrespective of the display mode matlab executed earlier.". I have wasted a lot of time searching for it. But I could not find any solution. Could you give me any solution?

Answer (score 0):

i think it works, try this:

```
axis off
set(myPlot, 'ButtonDownFcn', 'disp Goodbye')
```